# __getstate__ method not being called when pickling a subclass of set

Tags: python, pickle

From what I understand, when calling pickle.dumps on an object, it will call the object's __getstate__ method (if it has one) to determine what to pickle.

If I create a class such as:

```
class DictClass(dict):
    def __getstate__(self):
        print "pickling"
        return self
```

I get this result:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(DictClass())
pickling
'ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0...'
```

I can do the same thing, replacing 'dict' with 'list':

```
class ListClass(list):
    def __getstate__(self):
        print "pickling"
        return self

>>> pickle.dumps(ListClass())
pickling
'ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0...'
```

But if I use 'set', something different happens:

```
class SetClass(set):
    def __getstate__(self):
        print "pickling"
        return self

>>> pickle.dumps(SetClass())
'c__main__\nSetClass...'
```

The __getstate__ method doesn't get called. Why is this, and is it possible to specify what part of a subclass of a set to pickle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list` does not implement [`__reduce__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__), whereas `set` does:

```
>>> list().__reduce__()
...
TypeError: can't pickle list objects
>>> set().__reduce__()
(<type 'set'>, ([],), None)
```

It's the last tuple in the above example that gets pickled, so `SetClass.__getstate__()` never enters the picture.